# Proof by induction using logarithms

Tags: logarithms, induction

I have come across a question while studing for my exams
prove 
$$\log_2 x < x \text{ when }x>0$$

I know I have to solve it using a base case eg when $x=1$ then assume a inductive step $x=k$ is true but I'm having difficulty trying to solve when $x=K+1$
Can anyone help?

Comment: One thing to note is that induction only would only prove it for integers $x$, so it is important to make that clear in the statement of your proof. (It's true for all real $x>0$, but induction won't prove that...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Show that $\log(k+1) - \log(k) < (k+1) - k$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\log_2(k+1) < \log_2(2k) = \log_2 2 + \log_2 k = 1+\log_2 k < 1 + k.
$$

The first strict inequality holds whenever $k+1<2k$, and that happens whenever $1<k$.  So prove the result when $k=1$ or $k=2$ and go on from there.

You should not use both the lower-case $k$ and the capital $K$ interchangeably in mathematical notation.  Those should be treated as if they were two separate letters.  That is standard usage.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how I would do this problem:
Base case: If $x = 1$, then $$\log_2(x)=\dfrac{\log(x)}{\log (2)} = 0\lt 1$$

Assume when $x = k\ge 1$ we have $\log(k)/\log (2) \lt k$. Then $$\dfrac{\log(k + 1)}{\log(2)} \lt (k + 1)
\dfrac{\log(k + 1)}{\log(2)} \lt \dfrac{\log(2^{k+1})}{ \log (2)}$$

This proves the statement because if the logs were removed you would get $k + 1 \lt 2^{k + 1}$ which you know is true because the base case is true, and as the value on the left side increases linearly, the value on the right side increases exponentially.

Comment: How does this prove the statement for every $x>0$?